# change value of the instance attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

Is someone know how to change all the sides of this rectangle with 30.0 ?

I tried this but i get "None" result:

```
class Rectangle:

def __init__(self, height=50.0, width=40.0, color="white"):

    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.color = color

def area_calculation(self):
    return self.height * self.width

def change_square(self, side):
    self.height = side
    self.width = side

if __name__ == "__main__":
   NewRectangle = Rectangle()
   a=NewRectangle.change_square(30.0)
   print(a)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Comment: Does `change_square` return anything? What *should* `a` be?

Comment: expecting to change height to 30 and width to 30 too, thanks to my change_square function.

Comment: oh thanks it works :     def change_square(self, side):
        self.height = side
        self.width = side
        return self.height,self.width

Comment: i added : return self.height,self.width

Comment: As a general rule, you should *either* modify the `Rectangle` instance in-place and return `None` *or* return a new `Rectangle` instance, leaving the original unmodified. Don't modify it *and* return the modified value.